# Select child when multiple parents with same class - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, children

I would like to know you if it is possible with pure Javascript to select the child of every parent with the same class. For example:

```html
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category1</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category2</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category1</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category2</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

In this case, I need to select the  element of all the  and change the background color based on the category:
if the category is "Category1" background should be blue, if the category is "Category2" should be red and so on...

Comment: If you just want to change the styling, you could use CSS.`.parent > a {background-color: red}`, See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)  for more detail

Comment: The point is that these are dynamic contents. Therefore, the Javascript should say that (for example) if the category is "Category1" background should be blue, if the category is "Category2" should be red and so on...

Comment: Please share your code which you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.

By adding the class based on content.

```js
$('.parent a').each(function() {
     var className = $(this).html().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
     $(this).addClass(className);
});
```

```css
.category1 {
  color: orange;
}

.category2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category1</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category2</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category1</a>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, very appreciated. That Jquery script was exactly what I was looking for! I have another question, just for personal curiosity. Is there a way to rewrite the Jquery script in vanilla JS?

Comment: Try this..   <script>
  var parents = document.querySelectorAll('div.parent > a');
    parents.forEach(function(parent) {
      var className = parent.textContent;
      parent.className += className.trim().toLowerCase();
    })
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<div class="category_section">
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" rel="category tag">Category2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    //will get all anchor tags present inside category_section div
    $(".category_section").find('a').each(function(){

        //will get anchor tag text. Since you need to compare based on text.
        var category_value = $(this).text();

        if(category_value == 'Category1'){
            $(this).parent('.parent').css('background-color', 'blue');
        }
        else if(category_value == 'Category2'){
            $(this).parent('.parent').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    })
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the child element of the parent element. 
You can do this in jquery by

```
$( ".parent" ).children().css( "background-color", "blue" )
```

Or in Javascript only

```
  var child= document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
  for(var i=0; i<child.length; i++) {
     child[i].children[0].style.color = "red";
      //children[0] - means the first child, you can do some loop if you have multiple child
     }
  }
```